# Do variables passed to PDOObject::bindParam need to be initialized first?

Tags: php, pdo

Do variables passed to bindParam need to be initialized?

EDIT: REAL USE CASE

```
$user = 0; //IS THIS REQUIRED?
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Blah WHERE something=?");
$stmt->bindParam(0, $user);
foreach($array as $user)
   $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Can you tell me, why someone want to do this? Pass an uninizialized var to some functions is never a good idea - i.e. someone could pass an var with the URL to do something bad

Comment: @Philipp: In reference to the code in your now-removed non-answer: `register_globals` is usually disabled so users cannot create arbitrary variables by passing them via GET/POST. See my answer for cases where it would be ok to pass a reference to an unitialized variable

Comment: @ThiefMaster usually - but sadly now allways and I know some books which teach this technique

Comment: Those books should be burned. I don't think any somewhat recent PHP5 book still uses them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of param you bind. If it's an *out* parameter you don't need to initialize it. If it's an *in* or *inout* parameter you need to initialize it for obvious reasons.

In your case you should really initialize it since you are using it in the `WHERE` part, i.e. as an *in* parameter.

From the docs:

> ```
> bool PDOStatement::bindParam(mixed $parameter, mixed &$variable, ...)
> ```
>
> `variable`- Name of the PHP variable to bind to the SQL statement parameter.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the differences between In/Out parameters please?